# My times table js works, but not when I get initial value from input box. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

This js writes the times table for "var s", and it works:

```
var s = 3
var i = s;
var d =10*s
for (; i <= d; ) {
document.write(i+ "<br>");
i+=s;}
```

This other js is supposed to do the same thing as above, but using the value inserted in an input box.
But it only writes the inserted value. Could anyone please help me understand why?

```
function getInputValue(){
var s = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var i = s;
var d =10*s
for (; i <= d; ) {
document.write(i+ "<br>");
i+=s;}}
```

Thanks!

https://code.sololearn.com/WNN550TTE0SE

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="insert number" id="myInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Let's go</button>
    <br><br>
    <script>
        /*this js writes the times table for var s, and it works*/
        var s = 3
        var i = s;
        var d =10*s
        for (; i <= d; ) {
        document.write(i+ "<br>");
        i+=s;}
        /* this js is supposed to do the same thing as above, but using the value inserted in the input box. But it only writes the inserted value. Why?
        function getInputValue(){
        var s = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
        var i = s;
        var d =10*s
        for (; i <= d; ) {
        document.write(i+ "<br>");
        i+=s;}}*/
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All you have to do is add a parseInt() on "s", when you get a value from DOM it defaults to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting input it is returned as a string.

```js
var s = document.getElementById("myInput").value; // value is returned as a string
```

Later on when using the + operator is is concating(i.e joining) the number and string rather than adding them.

```
console.log(i) // 1
console.log(s) // "5" 
i+=s // this is the same as i = i + s
console.log(i) // "15"
```

The solution is to coerce(i.e. convert) the string into a number:

```
var s = Number(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
```

As a side note, this following multiplication expression works even if `s` is a string because if you have a number on the left and multiply a string it will coerce the string into a number:

```js
console.log(s) // "5"
var d = 10*s 
console.log(d) // 50
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to convert the input to an integer :

```js
getInputValue = () =>{
        var s = 3
        var s = parseInt(document.getElementById("myInput").value);
        var i = s;
        var d =10*s
        for (; i <= d; ) {
        document.write(i+ "<br>");
        i+=s;}

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="insert number" id="myInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Let's go</button>
    <br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively :

```js
getInputValue = () =>{
        var s = 3
        var s = document.getElementById("myInput").value *1;
        var i = s;
        var d =10*s
        for (; i <= d; ) {
        document.write(i+ "<br>");
        i+=s;}

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="insert number" id="myInput">
    <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();">Let's go</button>
    <br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```